# How to access an array in key-value pair in a javascript filter function

Tags: javascript

I want to figure out how many times/count the number 2 appears in variable "arr", the answer should be 2.  How do I access the array of numbers in the key called 'numbers'?

```
let arr = [{numbers:[2,2,3]}]
//how many times does the number 2 appear in the array above

let newArray = arr.filter(function(e){
  return e.numbers[0] == 2
})

document.write("Occurence of two:" + newArray.length + "<br>")
```

thanks, try out solution 
https://codepen.io/shihanrehman/pen/JybVJG

Comment: There are two arrays  `arr` and `numbers` so which array you need to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. You should take the inner array and filter it.

```js
let arr = [{numbers:[2,2,3]}]
//how many times does the number 2 appear in the array above

let newArray = arr[0].numbers.filter(function(e){
  return e== 2
})

document.write("Occurence of two:" + newArray.length + "<br>")
```

Comment: I guess that `"<br>"` is redundant `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the array that is numbers, not just the outer array.

```js
let arr = [{numbers:[2,2,3]}]
//how many times does the number 2 appear in the array above

let newArray = arr.map((object) => {
    return object.numbers.filter(element => element === 2);
});

document.write("Occurence of two: " + newArray[0].length + "<br>")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, reduce should be a better solution. However, if you insist in using filter, then use below code snippet:

```js
let arr = [{numbers:[2,2,3]}];
//how many times does the number 2 appear in the array above

let count = arr.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value.numbers.filter(v => v === 2).length, 0);

document.write("Occurence of two:" + count + "<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
newArray = arr[0].numbers.filter(function(e){
  return e == 2
})
```